# Sensor failure function override python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am using an **HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor** to measure the **distance between a surface**. According to the distance reading, one stepper motor(28BYJ-48 type stepper motor) ** changes the rotational direction**. The issue is sometimes ultrasonic sensors don't give readings, at that stage stepper motor not working. Is there any way to program the hardware for sensor failure override? Here in this task, I am using **python on RPi zero W** version board. My python version is the 2.7.x version.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM

ControlPin1 = [7, 8, 25, 24]

TRIGPIN = 9
ECHOPIN = 10

for pin in ControlPin1:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin, 0)

seq = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]]

seq2 = [[1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]]

seq3 = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]

    def distancemeasure():
        ########################################Center position start#############################################################
        global distance
        time.sleep(2)
    
    #     print("Distance measuring in progress")
        GPIO.setup(TRIGPIN, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(TRIGPIN, False)
        GPIO.setup(ECHOPIN, GPIO.IN)
    #     print("Waiting for sensor to stabalize")
        time.sleep(0.2)
    
        GPIO.output(TRIGPIN, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIGPIN, False)
    
        while GPIO.input(ECHOPIN) == 0:
            pulse_start = time.time()
    
        while GPIO.input(ECHOPIN) == 1:
            pulse_end = time.time()
    
        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
        #print(pulse_duration)
        distance = pulse_duration * 17150
        distance = round(distance, 1)
        print(distance)
        #print("distance", distance, "cm")
        #time.sleep(2)
    
    
    def verticalstepperclockwise():
        for i in range(10):
            for halfstep in range(8):
                for pin in range(4):
                    GPIO.output(ControlPin1[pin], seq2[halfstep][pin])
                    time.sleep(0.001)
    
    
    def verticalsteppercounterclockwise():
        for i in range(10):
            for halfstep in range(8):
                for pin in range(4):
                    GPIO.output(ControlPin1[pin], seq[halfstep][pin])
                    time.sleep(0.001)

def horizontalstepperclockwise():
    for i in range(20):
        for halfstep in range(8):
            for pin in range(4):
                GPIO.output(ControlPin[pin], seq[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.001)


def horizontalsteppercounterclockwise():
    for i in range(20):
        for halfstep in range(8):
            for pin in range(4):
                GPIO.output(ControlPin[pin], seq2[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.001)


def horizontalsteppernomove():
    for i in range(0):
        for halfstep in range(8):
            for pin in range(4):
                GPIO.output(ControlPin[pin], seq3[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.001)  



def rotataion():

    distancemeasure()
    time.sleep(2)
    if distance < 5 and distance > 3:
        verticalstepperclockwise()
        time.sleep(2)
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)


    if distance > 6 and distance < 10:
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()
        time.sleep(2)
        verticalstepperclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)


    if distance > 5 and distance < 6:
        verticalsteppernomove()
        time.sleep(2)
    horizontalstepperclockwise()  ## horizontal clockwise rotation#####################################################
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    distancemeasure()
    time.sleep(2)
    if distance < 5 and distance > 3:
        verticalstepperclockwise()
        time.sleep(2)
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if distance > 6 and distance < 10:
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()
        time.sleep(2)
        verticalstepperclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if distance > 5 and distance < 6:
        verticalsteppernomove()
        time.sleep(2)
    horizontalsteppercounterclockwise()  # horizonta rotation center position counterclockwise rotation#############
    time.sleep(1)
    horizontalsteppercounterclockwise()  # horizontal counterclockwise rotation######################################
    time.sleep(1)
    
    distancemeasure()
    time.sleep(2)
    if distance < 5 and distance > 3:
        verticalstepperclockwise()

        time.sleep(2)
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if distance > 6 and distance < 10:
        verticalsteppercounterclockwise()

        time.sleep(2)
        verticalstepperclockwise()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if distance > 5 and distance < 6:
        verticalsteppernomove()

        time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    horizontalstepperclockwise()  # horizontal clockwise rotation to center position#####################################################
    time.sleep(0.5)

    def processloop():
             while (1):
        
                rotation()
        
        

   t4 = threading.Thread(target=processloop)
   t4.start()
```

Comment: Well, that's up to you.  If you can detect when the ultrasonic reader failed, then don't move the darned motor.  And we can't tell anything without seeing your code.

Comment: I am sorry can you check it now.

Comment: And how can you tell if the ultrasonic doesn't read/